# CustomAuthenticationProvider doesn't get called spring-security 5.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have converted an app to use spring and spring security I am using version 5.2. When I try and login my CustomAuthProvider doesn't get called. It does hit the security endpoint 'login' in the jsp and has an anonymous role. Below are the relevant configs.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@Import({com.example.Configuration.class, WebSecurityConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {

 servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/mvc/*");
```

Register the DelegatingFilterProxy

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

The WebSecurity class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
                .userDetailsService(new UserDetails());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and().
                authorizeRequests(a ->
                    a.antMatchers(
                            "/resources/js/**",
                            "/resources/scripts/**",
                            "/login",
                            "/resources/styles/**",
                            "/resources/images/**",
                            "/resources/loginPage.jsp",
                            "/resources/forgotUserName.jsp",
                            "/resources/forgotPassword.jsp",
                            "/mvc/jsonInitialResponse/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/resources/resetPassword.jsp",
                            "/mvc/jsonResponse/**",
                            "/mvc/download/**",
                            "/resources/**"
                    ).authenticated())
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/resources/loginPage.jsp")
                .successHandler(new CustomeAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureUrl("/resources/loginPage.jsp?error=true")
                .and().anonymous()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/resources/loginPage.jsp")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable().cors().disable();

    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {......}

@Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
```

Any thoughts on what I may be missing? The CustomAuthenticationProvider isn't being called  and either is the supports() method.

````
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:359 - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:359 - queryString: both null (property equals)
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:383 - requestURI: arg1=/reinsurance-service-ui-war/resources/login; arg2=/reinsurance-service-ui-war/resources/images/icn-lock.png (property not equals)
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG HttpSessionRequestCache:95 - saved request doesn't match
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /resources/images/icn-lock.png at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /resources/images/icn-lock.png at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:100 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@418e8a7d: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 4503EBEA550D56CD4AF5506BC88E7576; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /resources/images/icn-lock.png at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /resources/images/icn-lock.png at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /resources/images/icn-lock.png at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:177 - Checking match of request : '/resources/images/icn-lock.png'; against '/resources/js/**'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:177 - Checking match of request : '/resources/images/icn-lock.png'; against '/resources/scripts/**'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:177 - Checking match of request : '/resources/images/icn-lock.png'; against '/resources/styles/**'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:177 - Checking match of request : '/resources/images/icn-lock.png'; against '/resources/images/**'
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:219 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resources/images/icn-lock.png; Attributes: [anonymous]
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:313 - /resources/images/icn-pencil.png reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:348 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@418e8a7d: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 4503EBEA550D56CD4AF5506BC88E7576; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:169 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@51ca55f0
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:351 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:120 - Chain processed normally
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:119 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3fe8aa9d, returned: 1
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:243 - Authorization successful
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:256 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:313 - /resources/images/icn-lock.png reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:169 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@51ca55f0
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:351 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:120 - Chain processed normally
2020-10-06 12:26:29 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:119 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed```
````

Comment: Based on my understanding of what your AppConfig class does, the Spring Security filter chain will only apply to URLs starting with /mvc. Since /login doesn't start with /mvc, requests that go to /login don't go through Spring Security's filter chain; in particular, they don't go through the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter that you define with formLogin(), and so no authentication happens. Try registering the filter chain for all requests and see what happens, maybe? (Your debug logs might tell you if Spring filters are firing, too.)

Comment: The filters are being hit, I have debug set and can see request for images and jsp being added. example logs below